# Arrayadapter.getcount null point exception

Tags: android, arrays

I am getting the following stack trace (below is a complete copy) , this gives me little or no indication as to where in a massive application it is when going wrong and user feedback is nothing beyond "It crashed".

Is there anything I can do to pinpoint this more ?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:291)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:689)
    at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onInvalidated(AdapterView.java:813)
    at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyInvalidated(DataSetObservable.java:43)
    at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated(BaseAdapter.java:54)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter$ArrayFilter.publishResults(ArrayAdapter.java:469)
    at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4701)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at [the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.getCount%28%29) for `ArrayAdapter.getCount()`:

```
   /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public int getCount() {
        return mObjects.size();
    }
```

Clearly mObjects is `null`, i.e. your ListView or other AdapterView-derived type is trying to use the adapter before you've initialized it with it's data.

Comment: Thanks, there is one adapter where I forgot to add a check, will add it and hopefully it will go away. No idea why I didn't think of that - sometimes you need that fresh pair of eyes

Comment: No worries. Note that the call comes in response to a Handler, suggesting a background thread is maybe signalling the UI thread when it shouldn't.

Comment: @ReubenScratton: The link was not working. Corrected it, please check.

Comment: @ReubenScratton actually i am getting similar error, Could you elaborate more :(

Comment: There's nothing more I can add. Look to where your adapter is initialized and ensure that it is set up correctly before any view code tries to use it.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is putting debug information before every call to getCount() using the Log class

```
Log.d("tag", "Trying to get count on line 50 class Test");
```

then open logcat and find the last entry of this log before the error occures. Then you have the right location of the crash.